# Build a BI tool with PHP frameworks / Ruby on Rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, business-intelligence

I get data from Oracle every 10 minutes, which I then import into a local MySQL database and use that for my data reporting.

However because of the growth of the simple application I build I'm now looking at building a bigger BI solution.

My only problem is that the data I get in doesn't have a primary id in the database, I import it with mysqlimport and the database tables have MEMORY engine.

So I started a bit in Rails (with beginners knowledge) and got stuck on the primary id part, and rails like a lot of other PHP frameworks assume I will do CRUD.

However for my app, it's all read only.

What do you suggest?
And what do you think is possible?

I'm willing to learn anything new to build an awesome BI tool with this data.

Thank you so much!

Comment: one quick comment - Ruby on Rails (aka "RoR") has *nothing* **whatsoever** to do with PHP directly: are you looking to write a combined application? Is there something wrong with using a tool like BIRT from Eclipse (http://www.eclipse.org/birt)?

Comment: Hi Warren, thanks for your response, i don't know anything about BIRT, although i did see it, and it looked to me like a desktop app to design?? i'm building a web BI app. any ideas?

Comment: The question needs to be rewritten as it's almost impossible to answer.

Comment: if the data from oracle does not contains primary id, simply add sequence into it ? or create auto_increment field for mysql table

Answer (score 0):

Use rails and push the data (1 row every 10 minutes right?) and let it generate the primary key (slow to load in your historical data).  Then you can create another table with date/time - in 10 minute increments and voila you've got part of the structure  ;).  If you swizzle the data as you load to take advantage of the XXXX_id relationships you can leverage all the rails goodness.

Comment: i get the entire new data refresh every 10 minutes..
does that change your answer a bit?